# Gaps in cocos2d infinite looping game

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am using this code to implement infinite looping, but I'v got gaps for 1-2 seconds every time the offscreen image coordinates are changed. Why do they appear? How to fix it? I am also using SpriteBuilder.

```
#import "MainScene.h"
static const CGFloat scrollSpeed =100.f;
@implementation MainScene{
 CCPhysicsNode *_world; 
    CCNode *_oneb;
    CCNode *_twob;
       NSArray *_bb;


}
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    _bb = @[_oneb, _twob];
}

-(void)update:(CCTime)delta{
  _world.position=ccp(_world.position.x - (scrollSpeed * delta), _world.position.y  ); // moving world
    for (CCNode *ground in _bb) {
        // get the world position of the ground
        CGPoint groundWorldPosition = [_world convertToWorldSpace:ground.position];
        // get the screen position of the ground
        CGPoint groundScreenPosition = [self convertToNodeSpace:groundWorldPosition];
        // if the left corner is one complete width off the screen, move it to the right
        if (groundScreenPosition.x <= (-1 * ground.contentSize.width)) {
            ground.position = ccp(ground.position.x + 2 * ground.contentSize.width, ground.position.y);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

EDIT: I changed -1 to -0.5. Works fine!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using small image for iPhone 3.5-inch on iPhone 4-inch simulator. What resolution of your background image?

EDIT: In my game I have an infinite loop, too. Maybe my code may help you? First background sprite should be **1137x640**, second **1136x640**. And you will never have gaps again! Hope it helps.

init method:

```
    backgroundSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
    backgroundSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    backgroundSprite.position = ccp(0,0);
    [self addChild:backgroundSprite z:0];

    backgroundSprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background2.png"]; 
    backgroundSprite2.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    backgroundSprite2.position = ccp([backgroundSprite boundingBox].size.width,0);
    [self addChild:backgroundSprite2 z:0];
```

tick method:

```
backgroundSprite.position = ccp(backgroundSprite.position.x-1,backgroundSprite.position.y);
backgroundSprite2.position = ccp(backgroundSprite2.position.x-1,backgroundSprite2.position.y);

if (backgroundSprite.position.x<-[backgroundSprite boundingBox].size.width) {
    backgroundSprite.position = ccp(backgroundSprite2.position.x+[backgroundSprite2 boundingBox].size.width,backgroundSprite.position.y);
}

if (backgroundSprite2.position.x<-[backgroundSprite2 boundingBox].size.width) {
    backgroundSprite2.position = ccp(backgroundSprite.position.x+[backgroundSprite boundingBox].size.width,backgroundSprite2.position.y);
}
```

Comment: Background images are 640:1136. Tested using 4-inch simulator. I just made screenshots smaller.

Comment: I found a solution before you posted edited answer :). I changed "-1" value to "-0.5".